# How to update and notify the ListView after updating its data in android

Tags: android

I have two activities, `ItemListActivity` and `ItemDetailsActivity`, and using listview and custom Adapter to display data view. After clicking the item the `ItemDetailsActivity` is called and record is updated using API. Now I am coming back to `ItemListActivity`, here I am not fetching the data from API because I am having the updated data in my hand. Here I just want to update that particular records of listview without reloading the entire records. If my process is wrong then suggest me the proper way because I am beginner in Android Development.

Code :

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String csThumbImageFld;
    try{
        final cGlobalData clsGlobal = (cGlobalData) getApplicationContext();
        csThumbImageFld = clsGlobal.getThumbImageFld();
        csThumbImageFld = csThumbImageFld == null ? "" : csThumbImageFld;
        if (!csThumbImageFld.isEmpty()) {
            s_UpdateItemView(csThumbImageFld);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        cMsgHandler.s_ShowError(this,ex.getMessage(), eEnums.eErrorType.Error);
    }finally {
        csThumbImageFld = null;
    }
}

private void s_UpdateItemView(String csThumbImageFld){
        View gridView;
        ImageView imgSS;
        byte[] decodedString;
        Bitmap oImg;
        try{
            gridView = MyDL.getChildAt(m_inPosition);
            imgSS = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.img_SS);
            if(!csThumbImageFld.isEmpty()){
                 decodedString = Base64.decode(csThumbImageFld, Base64.DEFAULT);
                 oImg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                 imgSS.setImageBitmap(oImg);
                 m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
         }catch (Exception ex){
             cMsgHandler.s_ShowError(this,ex.getMessage(), eEnums.eErrorType.Error);
         }
 }
```

Comment: `youradapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();` this might be the solution you're looking for

Comment: norifyDataSetchanged() on to your adapter will change the data without reloading it.

Comment: @Tejas Pandya, How to update the ListView item?? i am updating like ..
View gridView = MyDL.getChildAt(m_inPosition);
TextView lblName = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
lblName.setText("OM");
myAdap.NotifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you don't have to do anything . just when you came back from your second screen just notify your adapter (as i mentioned above ). It will automatically update your view with new content .

Comment: just for your reference . please [visit this link for detail info](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.widget.ArrayAdapter&method=notifyDataSetChanged)

Comment: @Tejas Pandya, I understood but how to update the content ? I have written a function called s_UpdateItemView(); that is called on onStart();, I have updated my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save click position when you goes to detail activity and when you come back to list activity, replace updated data at that position in array list. See code below:

```
arraylist.set(clickPosition,newData);
adapter.notifyDataSetchanged();
```